# Sequence of setTimeout in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

Can someone explain me, why if I create a function in JavaScript and add it to `setTimeout`, `setTimeout` doesn't work properly, but if I create anonymous function everything is okay? Example below:

**It works:**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    alert("foo");
}, 100);
```

**It doesn't works:**

```
function foo() {
    alert('foo');
}
setTimeout(foo, 100);
```

Comment: The scond code works fine. Is there something else we should know about?

Comment: Looks like it works, check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tj5ztubq/1/

Comment: https://github.com/elszczepano/Snake.js/blob/master/scripts/main.js can you see and tell me what is wrong? Line 89

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: There is no error. Just there is no timeout.

Comment: I just checked your code and everything works.

Comment: What's the issue here ? they work the same . both have timeout. just don't forget that time is in milliseconds ( for 1 second you have to put 1000 as timeout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your code, you are accessing snakeTail inside setTimeout callback. When callback function is executed after 100 ms the variable snakeTail is not available anymore. You should replace your line with

```
setTimeout(function(param){
    alert("Game over! Your score: "+(param-5)+" points. Wanna play again?");
    location.reload();
}, 100, snakeTail);
```

This way you can save the snaketail variable and pass it inside setTimeout callback.

Comment: Please mark as correct answer in case it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

### Undersatanding `setTimeout`

There is no difference, how to use it, passing anonymous function to `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("foo");
}, 1000);
```

Or passing an existing function:

```
function foo() {
    console.log('foo');
}
setTimeout(foo, 1000);
```

`setTimeout` is an **asynchronous**, so if you will use it before the regular `console.log`, the `console.log` after `setTimeout` function will be printed first, and then, the `console.log` inside `setTimeout` will be printed after specified delay (1 second in this case):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("bar");
}, 1000);
console.log("foo");
```

But if you want to log `"foo"` after 1 second and then to log `"bar"` after one second from `"foo"` was logged, you can add **2 second delay** to the second `setTimeout`, like this:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("foo");
}, 1000);

function bar() {
    console.log('bar');
}
setTimeout(bar, 2000);
```

Or alternatively you can wrap one `setTimeout` into another and give both of the 1 second delay. In this case, after 1 second will be printed `"foo"`, and after 2 seconds will be printed `"bar"`:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("foo");
    setTimeout(bar, 1000);
}, 1000);

function bar() {
    console.log('bar');
}
```

Hope this will give you the basic understanding of how `setTimeout` works.